# Authenticating and fetching data from couchdb using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, couchdb

I have a web app served by cherrypy. Within this app, I would like to fetch some data from a couchdb server, preferably using jquery. I am having trouble to authenticate into the server. When using:

```
$.couch.login({
    name: 'usename', 
    password: 'password', 
    success: function() {
        console.log('Ready!');
    }
});
```

It sends the login request to the cherrypy server, not the couchdb. According to [this](http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.db.html), I can use jquery.ajax settings and therefore I have tried using:

```
$.couch.login({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984',
    name: 'usename', 
    password: 'password', 
    success: function() {
        console.log('Ready!');
    }
    });
```

but it does not seem to work.
Any ideas? In addition, can anybody point me to good tutorial or simple web app developed in a similar fashion, i.e. a "standard" web page (not a couchapp), which contains jquery that gets info from couch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are currently doing is telling jquery.couch.js to login against that url. (It needs to POST to /_session)

I believe you need to set up the `urlPrefix` property on `$.couch`.

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = "http://localhost:5984/"; // run this before anything else with $.couch
```

Comment: $.couch.urlPrefix = "http://localhost:5984" did the job as I can see in the firebug net log that it is posting the login form to the right place. However, the success callback is not being called and in the console I only get "POST http://localhost:5984/_session 200 OK 50ms jquery.js (line 18)"

Comment: Can you see the contents of the response in the Net panel?

Comment: The response tab is empty, but if can see something in the response
headers:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: AuthSession=c2NyZWVuZnM6NEUyOUEwNDQ6WUQHCfIUh2q3Uc3SJj0brKtXmVo;Version=1; Path=/; HttpOnly
Server: CouchDB/1.1.1 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2011 16:07:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 43
Cache-Control: must-revalidate

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that inside a browser, JavaScript enforces the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Since the HTML page is presumably *not* being loaded from port 5984, you'll have figure out some clever way around it, such as [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) or [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).