# Javascript (JQuery/CouchDB) function doesn't work but only when called from button onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, couchdb

In my HTML head I first include jquery.min.js, jquery.couch.js and twitter-bootstrap js (in that order) and then I have a function called logmein() as follows:

```
<script>
$.couch.urlPrefix = "http://127.0.0.1:5984"
function logmein() {$.couch.login({
    name: "testuser",
    password: "test",
    success: function() { alert("Success!") },
    error: function() { alert("Login failed") }
    });
}
</script>
```

With username and password hard-coded for testing.

I then have a button:

```
<button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="logmein()">Sign in</button>
```

When I try and click submit, I get this error:

```
jquery.couch.js:216 TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'resp.error')
```

However, if I type logmein() directly into Safari's web developer console, it works just fine! What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I think it maybe related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792725/637562 though I don't quite understand why (to my knowledge, I was running it on the same protocol/host).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved"

If anyone else is having this issue, I'm still not exactly sure what caused the problem. Google Chrome gave a more detailed error message, suggesting the same origin policy had been violated, even though I don't believe this to be the case.

Despite this, there's a much simpler solution all without Javascript: the CouchDB Session API.

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="password" name="password">
<button id="submit">Sign in</button>
```

Where 127.0.0.1 is a local couchdb instance, and should be replaced with your couchdb server address....

More details here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Session_API including how to set up automatic page redirection on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your logmein function to run on the click event of #submit:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.couch.urlPrefix = "http://127.0.0.1:5984";
    $.couch.login({
        name: "testuser",
        password: "test",
        success: function() { alert("Success!") },
        error: function() { alert("Login failed") }
        });
});
```

Also, it seems that the urlPrefix should be inside the logmein() function

```
function logmein()
{
    $.couch.urlPrefix = "http://127.0.0.1:5984";
    $.couch.login({
        name: "testuser",
        password: "test",
        success: function() { alert("Success!") },
        error: function() { alert("Login failed") }
        });
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this, but it seemed to cause the function to be run on page load too...? Edit: I just tried this again, verbatim, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: See edits with the urlPrefix.  I am not familiar with couch, but it seems like the urlPrefix should be inside the function.

Comment: Okay, I tried this, and it gives the same error. Specifically, when I click submit, I get "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'resp.error')" and then the page refreshes. Whether the urlPrefix should be inside the logmein() function or not, as I said before, when I called logmein() directly from the console it *did* work, it only gives this error when called from the button (whether from onClick= or from $('#submit').click()). Hmm..